# How to convert pandas multiindex into table columns and index?

Tags: pandas

I have a DataFrame

[image]

It has a multi-index and each row has a value

I want to unstack it but it has duplicated keys. Now I want to convet it into this format:

[image]

where index1 and index2 is one of the multi-index, and index3 and index4 is another multi-index, value1~3 are values in the original df, if the value doesn't exist, the value is nan.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if this example helps you:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'value': [1, 3, 5, 8, 5, 7]}, index=[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'A']])

df = df.reset_index(level=1)
df = df.pivot_table(values='value', index=df.index, columns='level_1')
```

Original data:
[image: Original data]
Result:
[image: Result]

Comment: Yes! Exactly what I want! I solved the problem with pivot_table. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative way, you can use `unstack()`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'value': [1, 3, 5, 8, 5, 7]}, index=[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'A']])
df.unstack(level=1)
```

Original dataframe:

```
     value
1 A      1
2 B      3
3 A      5
4 C      8
5 C      5
6 A      7
```

Output:

```
  value          
      A    B    C
1   1.0  NaN  NaN
2   NaN  3.0  NaN
3   5.0  NaN  NaN
4   NaN  NaN  8.0
5   NaN  NaN  5.0
6   7.0  NaN  NaN
```